# Imagination-augmented na prática

Tags: tensorflow

Estou dando uma pesquisada sobre Imagination-augmented, gostaria de entender na prática como isso usando TensorFlow? Gostaria de saber as funções recomendadas para trabalhar dessa forma, e a lógica em si.